# Get File Path of a File Being Passed into MyApp Objective-C Mac

Tags: objective-c, macos, file, path, filepath

**I'm using** `-(void)application:(NSApplication *)sender openFiles:(NSArray *)filenames` **to preform an action when a file with .myfiletype at the end of the file name.**

I am also using `NSString *fileThing = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:@"/Users/baileyseymour/Desktop/myfile.myfiletype" 
encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];`
**to get the contents of a file but with a absolute path.**

***How can I make it so that I can get the path to the file being opened instead of the absolute path?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for each filename in the filenames array? Like this:

```
-(void)application:(NSApplication *)sender openFiles:(NSArray *)filenames {
    for (NSString *filename in filenames) {
        NSString *fileThing = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filename 
                                                        encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding 
                                                           error:nil];
    }
}
```

Comment: I will as soon as it will let me :)